# Facing issue to get the appropriate count

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I have a view which "web.individual_usage_vw".
Whose total count is = 39057.
SQL Query: `select count(*) from web.individual_usage_vw;`

In this view, it has few columns in which it has numeric data.

So I need to fetch all the records from view where data is > 1.

So I used below query:

```
select count(*) from web.individual_usage_vw 
where "Business & economy" != 0
and "Executive rewards" != 0
and "Health & benefits" != 0
and "Investment" != 0
and "Corporate marketing" != 0
and "Retirement" != 0
and "In General" != 0
and "Mergers & acquisitions" != 0
and "Corporate strategy operations" != 0
and "Broad-based rewards" != 0
and "Leadership" != 0
and "Talent" != 0
and "Other" != 0;
```

This result me with count **0**

Whereas

```
select count(*) from web.individual_usage_vw
where "Business & economy" = 0
and "Executive rewards" = 0
and "Health & benefits" = 0
and "Investment" = 0
and "Corporate marketing" = 0
and "Retirement" = 0
and "In General" = 0
and "Mergers & acquisitions" = 0
and "Corporate strategy operations" = 0
and "Broad-based rewards" = 0
and "Leadership" = 0
and "Talent" = 0
and "Other" = 0;
```

Result me with count = **36228**

I am not able to debug this error.

Comment: Use `OR` instead of `AND` in the first query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the results. The second query is fetching rows only when all your columns (in the predicate) are having 0. In your first query, you are fetching rows where all columns have non zero values. The missing records (delta) might be having one or more columns where the result is zero.

For example

```
C1, C2
0  0
1  0
1  1
0  1

select * from t1 where c1 = 0 and c2=0; -- returns one row

select * from t1 where c1 != 0 and c2!=0; -- returns one row and not three
```

Hence the difference. If you need to return all rows that are not returned in your second query then use `NOT EXISTS`

Roughly, this is what you need.

```
SELECT columns
FROM   table
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   table
                   WHERE  all columns = 0) ;
```